# Modules missing from installed package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed and am trying to use fbconsole: https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole/

Looking at the instructions, I can make the first couple of steps work:

```
import fbconsole

fbconsole.AUTH_SCOPE = ['publish_stream', 'publish_checkins']
fbconsole.authenticate()
```

But when I try

```
fbconsole.logout()
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'logout'

Looking at the file that's being installed, I do see both the authenticate() and the logout() module. Is the package not being installed correctly?

Comment: are you sure you haven't missed parens? like you've called it like `fbconsole.logout` instead of `fbconsole.logout()`?

Comment: Yea. I'm just copy-pasting from the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's work correct for me!

Reinstall fbconsole with this command:

```
python setup.py install
```

I hope it's work for you too!

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Is there same name with `fbconsole.py` or python package `fbconsole` in your python path?

If so then:

```
import fbconsole
print fbconsole.__file__
print dir(fbconsole)  # look if the logout in the fcconsole module
```

then watch the file of the fbconsole module you import is what,

If not , you can atempte to remove the fbconsole.pyc in your python path(just use the same above code) and looks is it works.